# Is topology invariant under conformal transformation?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, conformal-geometry

Can conformal transformation change the topology of a manifold?
In other words, if two manifolds are conformal, should they have the same topology?

Comment: Have you looked at the definition of 'conformally equivalent'?

Comment: It is easy to construct a conformal map which is not a diffeomorphism. Just take a  covering. For instance the natural exponential map $\bf R^2 \to T^2$ is conformal (even locally isometric) but not a diffeo. One also have plenty of examples with Riemann surfaces . So your question is not precise enough

Answer (score 4):

If $(M,g)$ and $(N,h)$ are conformally equivalent we have a diffeomorphism $f:M\rightarrow N$ such that $f^*h$ is conformally equivalent to $g$. Since $f$ is a diffeomorphism the topology on $M$ and $N$ are the same (they have the same open sets).

Answer (score -2):

I don't think they should have the *same* topology, but if $B_1$ is a topology base of your first manifold $S_1$, and $f$ is a conformal transformation such as $f(S_1) = S_2$ (where $S_2$ is your second manifold), my guess is that $B_2 = f(B_1)$ is a topology base of $B_1$... but I'm not sure of it